# Array of Interface in Java

Tags: java, arrays, interface

I have an interface.

```
public interface Module {
        void init();
        void actions();
}
```

What happens when i try to create an array like this?

```
Module[] instances = new Module[20]
```

How can i implement this array?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You cannot instantiate interfaces. What would the purpose of that be? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @user What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: I am not trying to achieve anything. I have a complex code that i am trying to understand.

Comment: @user You can create an object array using anonymous classes, see burna's answer.

Comment: @EboMike after some years may be you know, but this makes sense. One project in my company uses an interface (only get functions) which is implemented by a value object. And this interface is an array property of another value object. (ValueObject1 - Interface - ValueObject2)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

yes, it is possible. You need to fill the fields of the array with objects of Type `Module`

`instances[0] = new MyModule();`

And `MyModule` is a class implementing the Module interface. Alternatively you could use anonymous inner classes:

```
instances[0] = new Module() {
 public void actions() {}
 public void init() {}
};
```

Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 10):

You would need to fill the array with instances of a class(es) that implement that interface.

```
Module[] instances = new Module[20];
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    instances[i] = new myClassThatImplementsModule();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a concrete class type that would implement that interface and use that 
in your array creation

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can create an array whose type is an interface. You just have to put references to concrete instances of that interface into the array, either created with a name or anonymously, before using the elements in it. Below is a simple example which prints hash code of the array object. If you try to use any element, say myArray[0].method1(), you get an NPE.

```
public class Test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     MyInterface[] myArray = new MyInterface[10];
     System.out.println(myArray);
 }
 public interface MyInterface {
     void method1();
     void method2();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify accepted answer from @Burna, this array can be used to arrange collection of object, but it can never arrange its own interface in the collection, that is to put `Module` interface in `instances` reference variable. In JLS Chapter 10.6

> Each variable initializer must be assignment-compatible (§5.2) with the array's component type, or a compile-time error occurs.

But you can't use the interface `Module` in the initialization, because interface can't be instantiated (by definition). Thus you have to implement it first and arrange it in the array.